# Cordova, Ionic Framework and AngularJS - Angular datafactory behaviour

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-factory

I'm new to Cordova, Ionic Framework, and Angular and have hit a roadblock with using a factory.

My factory is setup as follows:

```
    angular.module('test.factories', ['ionic'])
.factory('dataFactory', function($http, $q, $timeout){
 dataFactory.getItems = function(search) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
 //rest of code to get stuff from SB works fine

//an array used to push items to from sqlite3 tx.executeSql 
returnData = []; 
deferred.resolve(returnData);
return deferred.promise;
}
}
```

All that works just fine, I get data into my controller, and if its a list the data renders just fine using `ng-repeat` in the view.

However, I can't access a specific item in the returned array:

```
dataFactory.getItems("name").then(function(results){
   $scope.results = results; //ng-repeat works fine with this
   var a1 = results[0]; //returns undefined
   for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++) { //doesn't enter the loop}
   console.log(results); //shows [{"item","value"}] - JSON.parse returns an error
   //chrome devtool bar shows it as an array, and I can drill down into the elements! so
  $scope.result = results[0]; //nothing is set
});
```

This is causing some confusion, and issues as in some instances only 1 item is returned, and I'd like to render specific properties in the view eg `{{result.property}}`

As I said, I'm very new to all these frameworks, so may have done something totally wrong with the factory, etc, but it's bugging me now lol how can an array be an array, but not ?!?

Any help would be most appreciated!

cheers guys

Comment: maybe the results are wrapped in an object. if you console.log the results inside `then` what do you see ?

Comment: the usual drilling down into array view, that's what's confusing me the most! I've tried eval() and all sorts.. 

Array[1]
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: JSON.stringify returns empty string
typeof() returns object

Comment: just print it to the console add see whats coming out. maybe it's malformed.

Comment: var output = "";
        for (var property in item) {
            output += property + ': ' + item[property]+'; ';
        }
        console.log(output); //empty 
        console.log(item.toString()); //undefined
        console.log(item); :
//Array[1]
0: Object - this expands into the json properties as expected
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

ahhh no formatting! tldr; - gives the object explorer view for an array

Answer (score 0):

BAHHHHH rookie mistake!!!

In my factory I had placed deferred.resolve(data) in the wrong place, I've now added it below the row iteration in the tx.executesql success function and all is well!

thanks for trying Haki